# How on earth did I fail this test?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

So I did some reviews and I stumpled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51917354/is-it-possible-to-get-the-expansion-of-a-single-macro-instead-of-the-whole-file) question. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20787424) my review of it.

This question was just a link to another question with the OP's question as the question title. I've already saw that kind of question some times ago and they always got downvoted to the bottom of hell.

So what did I wrong? Or did I do even something wrong?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Update**

I've asked the support to delete this audit, but before I did so, I came back to the question. And oh wonder, it looks like this now:

[image]

I've explained the support the issue with this question (random upvotes and then got downvoted a lot), and this was their reply:

> Hi CodeF0x,
>
> Thank you for reporting this bad audit. It's very clearly a bad audit,
>   so I'm going to lift your current review ban. You've hit a few bans in
>   the past, is why the length, but in this case it's pretty clear that
>   it was an unfair result.
>
> As for the post itself - it shouldn't show up in audits anymore. Posts
>   at -3 or worse, as well as closed posts (which this one seems to be on
>   its way to) are exempt from being picked as audits. It seems it got
>   picked up for you randomly at the one bad window where it didn't fail
>   those criteria.
>
> - The Stack Overflow Team

---

Thanks to the support it's all good now :).

Comment: *How on earth did I fail this test?* you clicked the wrong button ... ;)

Comment: Not all tag followers vote the same. So what is deemed low quality in one tag is ok in another.

Comment: People upvoted it, which probably make the audit consider as not bad quality. The question is quite short, but this doesn't seem like it need more information to answer it. As for the topicness of the question, I don't think we're that much off the mark either. Don't worry too much about failing audit once from time to time. It isn't perfect.

Comment: @rene Sure, seems like people find the question good, but -- seen in an objective way -- isn't this question simply against the rules?

Comment: I admit the question is terse and you need some mind bending to digest it but it is not off-topic, too broad or opinion based. And I guess that for a rust developer it isn't unclear either. I guess it could benefit from an edit but if you had chosen that option in triage I guess you would still have failed the audit.

Comment: How could this answer have gotten 5 upvotes?? If a question can be answered with a link to another SO question, then its a duplicate. There is no reason to post an answer with the link.

Comment: @BDL, it's a question. all the information are in the question title. The body is just a link. disturbing

Comment: @DragandDrop: I completely missed that this is a question. Probably because of the missing question in the body.

Comment: Flagging that question for Unclear what you're asking

Comment: The edit on that question seems awful to me. I'm not knowledgeable on rust, so I just don't understand it. It might've been a decent question defaced with a bad edit. That makes the audit near-impossible.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think the question was a *good* one, but it was on-topic. I absolutely don't understand how it got *so many* upvotes (and it smells like some kind of manipulation to me).