# UX research time! May 2019 and the reputation system

Tags: discussion, reputation, user-experience, ux-research-time

Hello! This is our second installment of UX research updates for Meta. You can check out the first installment [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381508/ux-research-time-march-2019-and-the-user-profile-and-settings).

This month, I’ll talk about findings from user research we did last year about **how users with lower reputation perceive and use reputation and privileges.**

### Research background

This research was motivated by earlier qualitative research that found many users consider the reputation system to be a barrier to participation. In order to participate “in a more quiet way, like upvoting answers,” users need to get reputation. But in order to do so, they need to participate in more visible but daunting ways, like asking and answering questions. As one user stated:

> “I feel like I joined Stack Overflow too late. I feel stuck at the
>   bottom because I have almost no reputation and can’t do much.”

**The goal of this research was to get broader insight into lower reputation users’ interactions with reputation**, specifically:

- What do people with lower reputation know about reputation and privileges?
- How, if at all, are they motivated by this system?

We conducted 1:1 user interviews with recently active Stack Overflow users with <=100 reputation, sourced from our [research email list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx7In.png). Out of respect for people’s privacy, any quotes I’ve included here have been paraphrased.

Also, note that we consider users of all reputation levels to be important parts of the Stack Overflow ecosystem, and this research doesn’t seek to invalidate the broad range of experiences that users have with reputation. Rather, it seeks to gain more insight into a large but less visible segment of users and their experiences with the reputation and privileges system.

### What do people with lower reputation know about reputation and privileges?

Users **vaguely understood how the reputation system works** (“If your answer is good, you get more points”). Most were **unsure of what privileges they currently had or how to unlock the next privilege**.

> “I tried to comment and it told me I couldn’t. If I could comment, I
>   would say things like ‘I did this and it worked.’ It’s a contribution,
>   but it’s not different enough to be an answer.”

Most participants **didn’t know they could earn reputation by editing other people’s questions and answers**. When they learned about this option, they were **averse to the idea** of editing other people’s content.

> “Editing another person’s question without them knowing would be
>   weird. How I see someone’s question isn’t the way that they see their
>   question.”

### How, if at all, are they motivated by this system?

Participants were **uninterested in earning reputation as part of the “game”**.

> “The idea of helping others is good in itself. I don’t need privileges
>   to answer questions or to get more rep.”
>
> “More relevant questions [to answer] would incentivize me. I’m not
>   motivated by points.”

Participants primarily expressed interest in **earning privileges about core Q&A** (eg. voting, commenting) that would **make their existing tasks easier**. They were either uninterested or unaware of privileges that would introduce new interactions to their experience, such as the community wiki, chat, or moderation.

> “Privileges allow you to do things you’re already doing more easily…
>   for me to want privileges, it would have to ease my interaction… and
>   save time.”
>
> “The only ones I really cared about were basic things like comment on
>   answers (to be able to join in on discussion).”

### Next Steps

✌️Thanks for reading! This research was exploratory and is one of the inputs used when determining our product strategy. If you’d like to participate in future user research sessions, you can join the research email list via your [email settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current).

If there’s any research insights you’re interested in seeing, let me know in the comments! In the meantime, what have been your experiences with reputation and privileges, and what motivates you to participate in Stack Overflow? How, if at all, have these things changed if you’ve gained reputation over time?

Comment: Can you do the next one on what makes a question interesting for long-time users, how they find such questions, and how we might encourage more of them?

Comment: Thanks @DanBron! We have some upcoming research that dives into the expert/teacher perspective about how folks are learning to code. This probably won’t dive into your specific questions in granular detail, but it might still be interesting to you. I’ll see about sharing these findings for our next research post.

Comment: "I would say things like ‘I did this and it worked.’  It’s a contribution" It sounds like we need to do a better job of teaching users to contribute such 'me too's as upvotes rather than comments. The latter are not actually worthwhile contributions (if that quote's actually verbatim what the user would say).

Comment: It would be nice if upvotes from sub-15-rep felt more like real upvotes: keeping the vote button marked for that user (even if the score doesn't go up), instead of instantly undoing it and pushing back. You could also consider showing anonymous vote counts to the posts' author (while keeping them hidden in general) so users who just want to say "thank you" have a satisfying way to do so.

Comment: @TylerH I think that’s part of it. Another part is that people’s expectations about how to use features like commenting and voting are set by patterns on the rest of the web. So when, for example, we have very specific rules about how to comment that diverges from patterns that users have come to expect from sites like, say, Facebook, we have to consider the costs/benefits of that divergence, and if there’s a way to achieve the result we want without necessarily requiring users to learn new patterns when they come here.

Comment: If they do not need to learn new patterns, then there is no difference.  If there is no difference, then SO is facebook. No?

Comment: Don’t think I want to post an answer, but I’ll stick my oar in for the heck of it. Things are moving towards an unsustainable model, where everyone speaks, and no one listens. MOST (not SOME -MOST) high-rep people have less than 20 questions. A number have 0. I consider that problematic.

Comment: This site rewards broadcasting, and actually penalizes receiving. I can’t speak for anyone else, but I come here to get work done. When I ask a question, it’s because I have an actual, shipping project I’m working on, and need to find the best solution to a specific issue. This site is incredibly valuable to me, because I can get orthogonal points of view in solving my dilemma.

Comment: There’s a meta post somewhere, that is often referenced, something like “when should I ask a question?”, and the accepted answer is “almost never.” In my opinion, that’s an issue. It exposes the mindset that people that ask questions are “less than,” and shows actual contempt for those that ask, as opposed to answer.

Comment: Can’t say it’s entirely wrong, as “Do my homework” is annoying and noisy, but I don’t come here to answer. I come to ask. Most times, my question is answered before I ask, but sometimes, I have a particular issue that I know how to solve, but I want to solve *better*. I can get some extremely valuable insight here, and deeply appreciate the site.

Comment: I could definitely contribute a lot of answers, and rack up a fairly impressive score, if I wanted to, but that’s not why I come here. It is a bit galling to be sneered at by people who are deeply invested in a subject, but I don’t mind too much, as long as I get the answer I need. Just my $0.02.

Comment: @RiftValleySoftware The problem with the "anything goes" approach is that it doesn't work. Allow any kind of question and you won't get any anwsers anymore. The amount of time time I need to sort out the garbage question and find answerable ones is already putting me off. There is value in insisting on high quality questions.

Comment: @Jeremy *"It would be nice if upvotes from sub-15-rep felt more like real upvotes: keeping the vote button marked for that user"* - and then what happens when they reach 15 rep? Do their old votes become real votes? Or does the vote button revert to its unclicked appearance at *that* point? Both would perhaps be slightly problematic in their own ways.

Comment: @MarkAmery why would the former be a problem? They were going to vote on the content anyway. And you get 15 rep soon enough if you're active, so it's not like your "old clueless votes" suddenly become real. You won't be that much more experienced in what to upvote when you reach 15.

Comment: "We conducted 1:1 user interviews with recently active Stack Overflow users with <=100 reputation" seems to conflict with "Also, note that we consider users of all reputation levels to be important parts of the Stack Overflow". How many 1:1 interviews did you conduct with higher-rep users?

Comment: @RiftValleySoftware - *"MOST... high-rep people have less than 20 questions. A number have 0. I consider that problematic"*. As a member of that demographic I want to say that I ask SO for solutions all the time. The thing is, I use search (or Google) to find answers. Isn't that a form of listening? Still I look forward to the day when the SO hivemind hasn't already answered a question I want to ask.

Comment: @APC Fair 'nuff. I'm obviously in a lesser demographic, then. I find that I still need to ask a question, every now and then. I have a LOT of them. Like I said, though, it's a bit galling to be treated shabbily. I won't do that to anyone else; and one reason is that ol' "mile in a moccasins" thing. My being in a lesser demographic gives me empathy towards folks in that demographic. I know what it's like to be patronized by kids half my age, with half my experience. But if they have valuable stuff to say, I'll still listen to them.

Comment: @AndrasDeak You get 15 votes soon enough if you're actively *posting*. But unusual users will exist; if I've silently upvoted thousands of posts at 1 rep, and then finally post something myself and get upvoted, does a huge rep injection happen instantly? Are the votes back-dated, maybe drastically changing users' rep graphs retroactively, or do lots of users instantly hit the 200-rep-per-day threshold? Also, what if I've *downvoted* hundreds of answers before hitting 125 rep? Does my rep get smashed back down to 1 the moment they become ":real" downvotes and I pay the rep tax for each of them?

Comment: @Trilarion I understand perfectly. I run a fairly intense open-source project that caters to folks with a less-developed tech baseline. I'm constantly asked to do things in code that can be answered with "do it in CSS." So now, when I answer, I always say "IT Support. Have you tried turning it off and then on again?"

Comment: @MarkAmery yeah, I guess downvotes would be more problematic. I figured votes could be cast at the time of the user reaching the threshold. Oh well.

Comment: ...and one more thing. As I'm working on shipping software, time is a definite coefficient. I'm frequently in a "blocker" situation, or in one where I need to get the final design in place ASAP. In these cases, I need the answer *QUICKLY*. 99% of the time, a simple Google will give me the SO answer I need, but sometimes (often, when there's a bug in the tools), I need to be sure.

Comment: I cannot emphasize enough the need for patience, kindness and empathy. These are traits that we all need to cultivate. Those of us old enough to remember The September That Never Ended can remember the Internets going down the tubes; but what most folks don't like to admit, is that the ones that posted the most vile stuff were the experienced folks that already "lived" in the Internet. Everyone likes to say that it was the "flood of n00bs" that destroyed the Internet, but I think it was the current residents that became the first trolls.

Comment: I like to think of myself as a good citizen. I treat people with kindness and professionalism; even if they don't do the same to me. Some folks will interpret a simple inflexible boundary as "arrogance," and I can't do anything to help that, but I feel that it's important for me to *model* the behavior I would like to see in others. My behavior has almost nothing to do with yours. I keep my own score, and I do, in fact, help a *LOT* of folks. It's that this isn't the venue in which I do that. I remain eternally grateful to this site, and evryone in it, for the excellent help that I get.

Comment: what motivates: rep & helping others

Comment: re: Rep and Helping others. If I had a reliable way to find a question that a) isn't answered & accepted by the time I finish working on an answer and b) is interesting enough and answerable and c) not a duplicate, I'd answer a lot more, like daily. Unfortunately, in the tags I have expertise in none such exist.

Comment: @RiftValleySoftware Sounds like you're making a case against the "Optimizing for pearls, not sand" principle (i.E questions are plentyful but answers need to be optimized for). That principle is the reason why questions are decidedly second class citizens to answers, i.E why upvotes on them are worth half as much, or why downvoting them is free.

Comment: @Magisch I'm not making a case *against* anything. I am saying that it's disappointing to encounter some of the cruelty that I see on other sites, but I guess that can't be helped. At least the SO ToS means that they use nicer words, but I was brought up by a British mum, so I have a great deal of experience with people using advanced and eloquent vocabulary to slice other people apart. Like I said, in the aggregate, things are fine here, but I will bring up "why can't we just be civil to each other" whenever I get the chance.

Comment: The reason it got this way to start is that getting enough questions is automatic and easy. Questions and their askers are a dime a dozen. Actual experts willing to answer these questions are not. SO has built its success primarily on the face of catering to the experts solving questions to a wide enough degree that they choose this platform over another to answer on. You're probably right, it's pretty cruel that the general attitude and reality of asking is "You're one of already too many, so better put your best foot forward", while it's nothing like that for answers. I'm just not

Comment: convinced that it can be any other way without making the experts leave, which in turn will cause the askers to also leave because what use is a Q/A site where nobody will answer your question. It's a fact of the inherent power imbalance between the people providing (answers) and the people wanting (answers) when no money is involved. It's akin to going to the github of an OS author and asking for a feature. You'll be regarded as less important than than the author for the very same reason, which expresses itself in differences on how you're treated and what's expected from you

Comment: @Magisch Good points. In some ways, I have a great deal of valuable stuff to contribute. However, I'm not particularly interested in competing for the brass ring. This site rewards competition; not cooperation.

Comment: @RiftValleySoftware Thats a big issue I have myself with the system, as said above. I love digging in to solve a problem, but I'm not really that expert at quick thinking and at the start of my career. It's dampening to be beat to the punch on an easy question by someone with 5 times your experience and then being told you're duplicating their answer. I can relate. It's why I primarily like to do novel and/or background contribution stuff these days.

Comment: Most of the time I try to write posts that will be useful for the long term, and am happy to wait years for the thank-you upvotes to slowly come in. Understandably, that approach might not be appealing for users who are working for their first privilidges. I'm also getting slightly back into rep hunting mindset now that 100k is attainable, but that's still like two years away.  And then I can pour all my future rep into bounties.

Comment: I agree with optimizing answers over questions.  I was a frequent contributor of answers on Quora before they started paying money for questions.  Suddenly I understood why it was flooded by stupid questions.  Like others, I implicitly ask questions on SO several times a day by googling my question.  Much of the time the important answer is found on a Stack Overflow site.  If you check me out, I am a lower reputation user, but I consider myself to be pretty active on SO, and interested in the success of this model.

Comment: It's probably not an exaggeration to say that I've asked 20 times more questions then I've ever answered on SO, although only less then 10 of those made it to a post. I do get help and immeasurable time saved daily from this site via looking at answers, though.

Comment: Here's my [five-year-old answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252989/241211) to @Donna's questions. :-)

Comment: I've only recently bumped over the 200 rep threshold which allowed me to gain the 'base' 100 rep in other communities.  I was trying to suggest edits to other people's answers to gain rep, but usually a single typo in a question was too small to submit.  That was discouraging from an engagement point of view.  - Unrelated, I also was very active in puppet's (now deprecated) ask.puppet.com, as one of the top contributors to their self-hosted stackoverflow.  I wish there was some way to get my contributions and expertise to transfer over to SO proper...

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave — sometimes we conduct research to compensate for areas where we don’t have a lot of visibility, like I mentioned in the post. We have a pretty good preliminary idea of how higher rep users feel about with reputation thanks to places to Meta. That being said, were we to start thinking about changes to reputation, we would still step back and conduct more extensive research with all affected user groups, including high rep folks.

Comment: This is a great post Donna. Makes me less afraid to publicize results of qual research!

Comment: *"...any quotes I’ve included here have been paraphrased."* Don't call them *quotes* then.

Comment: It's not hard to get 100 rep, people who cant obviously SO is not for them... https://stackoverflow.com/users/9518140/icannowcomment?tab=profile

Comment: @LawrenceCherone The usage pattern you have to use to get to 100 rep (by which I mean FGITW) may be very different from the pattern a particular person would have if they reached 100 rep. It's easy to get discouraged and quit forever rather than churn out quick answers to bad questions, especially if your expertise is in low-traffic tags.

Comment: Perhaps we could suggest to new users that they search for posts containing [commonly misspelled words](https://www.inc.com/melanie-curtin/the-10-most-commonly-misspelled-words-in-english-language.html) and edit those. I searched for “definately”: 3,451 results! Usually such posts will have several other things that need to be fixed. That could at least get them past 10 rep. Wish I had thought of this when I started—took me at least a month to get past 10.

Comment: @DennisT - I have tried to do edits like that when initially building rep, but my edits were too short and couldn't be submitted....

Comment: [@Cinderhaze](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3543867), maybe half of them would be like that but there are still so many. E.g., [2nd q on the "definately" list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14801955) is a good example. You can change "been sat here" to "been sitting", "i've" to "I’ve" and then the "definately" at the end. More than 6 chars and there’s still some left over: punctuation mistakes that I haven’t mentioned.

Answer (score 86):

> What have been your experiences with reputation and privileges?

Eh.

(not really sure what this means)

> What motivates you to participate in Stack Overflow?

Originally it was the rep, the gamification of the system was interesting to me. However, I noticed that as I grew and matured as a developer and being exposed to meta (and the ethos of this site as a whole) my views/focus shifted quite a bit to the curating aspect of the site.

> How, if at all, have these things changed if you’ve gained reputation over time?

Truth be told, the more privileges I gained the more respect I gained for the folks who've been working hard to maintain the quality standards of the site for such a long time. Without some of the privileges you can't really see the insane number of outright terrible questions that get handled in the background by dedicated users whose sole intention is to keep the site clean and easier to use for the vast majority of the everyday users.

Comment: The first question is a general prompt to let us know how the reputation system has worked for you. I think you covered it pretty well in the rest of your answer. ;-) I [echo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141021/1438) your appreciation for the people who work day in and day out keeping the site orderly.

Comment: I would have struggled to write this better myself. I totally agree with your sentiment.

Answer (score 76):

> Editing another person’s question without them knowing would be weird. How I see someone’s question isn’t the way that they see their question.

This tells me they haven't grasped SO's core mission: to create a high quality knowledge repository. While SO is itself averse to changing the intent of the author, we highly *encourage* improvements to formatting, language, and clarity. The question does not *belong* to one person, even though one person is the driver of the question's intentions.

> Participants primarily expressed interest in earning privileges about core Q&A (eg. voting, commenting) that would make their existing tasks easier. They were either uninterested or unaware of privileges that would introduce new interactions to their experience, such as the community wiki, chat, or moderation.

Again, this tells us that they're not grasping SO's core mission. This line of thinking is focused instead on posting a lot of questions and answers and on getting personal help rather than *using the existing content* to improve their knowledge. **We don't want people to post a lot of questions and answers.** We want users who [are capable researchers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1394393), who will dig into a problem and do their best to come to a solid understanding of it *before* they post a question. We don't need 500 personal debugging questions a day that no one is ever going to see again. Quantity is not the way to get quality.

It is unsurprising that most users view SO as merely a source of free labor to help them personally. We've always known that most of the internet population has this attitude. It contributed heavily to [the downfall of Usenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September), after all.  Most people simply do not wish to invest their time into creating a resource for someone else to use. I don't blame them for this; doing so is time consuming and difficult. But it's a reality we must face if we hope for SO to retain its initial goals. Staving off that outcome was one of the major reasons SO put quality controls in place.

What worries me most is that there's absolutely no mention of any of this in the post. Implicit in this research is that SO is interested in getting more users to engage *more* with this platform, but *over-engagement* is already a serious problem. Why not instead focus on changing the site in a way that helps people find the info they're looking for *without* making a new post?

Comment: So how do you propose that they conduct research that will improve quality?

Comment: @CoderJoe See the last sentence.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts @jpmc26. Re: editing — maybe, but the findings also tell me that editing someone’s content on SO, at least within the current state, is not an intuitive action for many people. Ideally we’d find a way to drive SO’s core mission while appealing to people’s natural inclinations instead of working against them.

Comment: Re: your last question — if the system was perfect, then we’d absolutely focus on helping people find info better :) However, we know that many people struggle with the current system, and in some cases that’s because the system itself is flawed. Research like this helps us understand the problem more holistically without presuming what the solution should be.

Comment: @Donna SO has already presumed that increased participation is the solution. You need only glance at the Welcoming push to see that.

Comment: Agreed. Reputation blocking off new (low reputation) users from doing things we don't want means the reputation system is working-as-designed.

Comment: The only UX issue is how permission denial is communicated: whether as "permission denied, insufficient reputation to post comment" or "SE is about high quality answers to high quality questions, not about conversational comments. As a new user, we're not sure we can trust you to use the commenting feature properly, so you can't add comments yet. If you want to add a high quality answer, you can do that right now [with a link]. If you want to edit your question to improve its quality, you can do that right now [with a link]."

Comment: @Donna "we know that many people struggle with the current system": struggle *how*. The [tour] itself opens with "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum." Everyone (only a reputation of 1 needed) [may create posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts). That is, may ask high quality questions or provide high quality answers. The main problem is that although the system *permits* them to do so, typically they lack the professionalism or enthusiasm to do so. No amount of UX improvement can fix that.

Comment: "How I see someone’s question isn’t the way that they see their question." This seems mostly related to intent though. Changing the intent of a question is not ok.

Comment: @Lundin Even assuming you're correct, that shouldn't be a barrier to *all* editing activities. It indicates that whoever wrote it does not understand the kinds of edits we encourage. It indicates not knowing the site's culture or even rules.

Answer (score 46):

As someone with a range of rep values on stacks around the network, from 101 association bonus to 25k+, let me say:

> “More relevant questions [to answer] would incentivize me. I’m not motivated by points.”

Is ***enthusiastically*** seconded!

Comment: I'll add a third to that - I've seen 0 questions that are even close to interesting in the last few years. I looked today to make sure. Out of the 9 Qs: only one was really answerable, *w/simple edit-distance algo which someone already gave*, while 4 made me immediately want to comment *"what have you tried?"*. In fact, one of these was **a homework assignment from a course I taught**. Each of these 4 had answers already despite the lack of research & effort and no downvotes Whether due to "welcome wagon" scaring away comments or the people I worked with in that tag also leaving - I don't know

Comment: @JGreenwell During the past 5 years, the site has consistently been lowering the quality bar, in order to make it easier to ask questions, at the cost of question quality. It used to be a requirement that you actually had to have some minimum knowledge of the topic in order to ask a question. This is long gone, and so we get tons of questions that could easily be answered by reading chapter 1 in a beginner-level programming book, or by taking classes. Students started to use SO as an interactive beginner tutorial instead of using traditional means of learning.

Comment: And this does of course in turn drive away professional programmers and experts, since they signed up for professional programming Q&A and not to be  homework tutors (or parents for that matter, teaching how to interact with other human beings). Which in turn means even less interesting questions, when the experts leave.

Answer (score 19):

> What have been your experiences with reputation and privileges?

I generally like the system and the gamification, I enjoy working my way up and unlocking new abilities.

> What motivates you to participate in Stack Overflow?

To me my reputation is like a symbol of how far I've grown as a developer. I had an account on stack about 7-8 years ago when I was 13 and I just started teaching myself how to make websites. I of course posted horrible questions that always were downvoted and I never posted any answers or did anything further on the site.

> How, if at all, have these things changed if you’ve gained reputation over time?

As I got older and became a more knowledgeable programmer, I remember how hard it used to be to get rep on this site and today having just a little over 500 rep is really a big milestone for me.

So, while my focus is on the betterment of the site and I love answering questions in my field of expertise, the reputation system is of ever-growing importance to me because it signifies my growth as not only a developer but as a contributing member of this society.

Comment: Thanks for sharing and congrats on hitting the 500 rep milestone :)

Comment: And my condolences that one person being removed has brought you back under 500 rep again :)

Answer (score 18):

Reputation serves a purpose insofar as the system can leverage it to increase overall stability. As far as the number itself, I don't think that many users care that much for it on a numeric basis of trying to compete.

Instead, I think that reputation is a nice representation of the hard work that we have put into creating content here. I have just over 2,000 combined posts on Stack Overflow, and expressing that in a single number is very efficient. So, for me, it is nice to have an easy way of identifying the level of contribution.

Beyond that, it is only a measure of what has occurred in the past. Most of us are here to help users going forward, and in that regard, it is more important to focus on what drives progress more than what represents past effort.

Comment: +1, I agree there is value in having some sort of easy way to identify the level of contribution.

Comment: @Donna - I personally think that reputation can be stale at a certain point (essentially over 20k). It is kind of like, once you get to 21 (in the US at least), there are no more milestones to look forward to.  In this sense, it may be wise to incorporate more modern gamification systems into reputation. For example, I know that there is a "reputation league" where in some obscure place the leaders are posted. However, it is just a sorted list and that is it.

Comment: In order to modernize reputation, it could be beneficial to create seasons of reputation, where all of your privileges are based on the previous season's earnings combined with the current season's earnings. Earning 10k in a year is not *that* difficult, so having the season be something where you have to push a little bit in order to reach max privilege would land in the 9 month ballpark. User's flair would display the current season's reputation. User's profile would show a historical total along with a breakdown by season of totals, current ranks, etc.

Comment: This would allow the system to feel more competitive, incentivize users to be more content creation oriented, remove the problem of stale reputation, and also remove the feeling of new users not being able to compete with entrenched reputation.

Comment: really interesting ideas around stale reputation. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Somewhat similarly, Discourse's [Trust Level 3 "Regular" privileges](https://blog.discourse.org/2018/06/understanding-discourse-trust-levels/) are partially based on your activity in the last 100 days. If you don't maintain sufficient activity, you fall back to Trust Level 2 "Member" privileges.

Comment: @Jeremy, why would your trustworthiness degrade?

Comment: @TravisJ "Earning 10k in a year is not that difficult" - Really? That depends on completely on your area of expertise. That's too narrow a focus IMO. In the low-traffic tags that target is simply not possible.

Comment: @StephenRauch Because you may not be as in-touch with recent community policies or events. You're still somewhat trusted. Stack Overflow is a different site now than it was four or eight years ago; users who have been away for a long time might not be as qualified to moderate. Or users who spend so much time on moderation that they forget what it's like to be an author. I'm not sure what (if any) policy along these lines would make sense for Stack Overflow, but it's something I've been thinking about since seeing Discourse's setup.

Comment: @CindyMeister - Some of our top earners here earn 10k per month.

Comment: @Jeremy - I agree. People's participate rates can fade over time as well, which is another point to make along with your others. I have had extensive discussions in the tavern over the years on this topic, sometimes things take a while to gain traction.

Comment: @TravisJ I really like your suggestion, but I'm also worried to see a decline in users able to moderate. I myself for example come online once every now and then, when I got an hour to spend, or when I'm looking for a solution for a problem I'm facing. Especially when I have just an hour to spend I tend to glance over the newest questions to see if there is anything to answer. Usually I wade through a lot of sub-par questions and use my moderating abilities there (edit/CV). If I had to spend more time on maintaining the rep to be able to curate content I see two problems:

Comment: These problems are intertwined: First is that I need to find more questions I can answer, to maintain my curation abilities. Result of that is that I have to spend less time on questions that I can't answer / aren't answerable / don't deserve an answer. Result of that would be I don't edit and (close)vote as much. If others face the same dilemma more sub-par questions remain on the site. Which would be detrimental to the quality of the site in the long run. We could ofcourse make auto-deletion of questions more strict to remedy that problem, but I feel thats less fair in some way.

Comment: @Travis *"I personally think that reputation can be stale at a certain point (essentially over 20k). It is kind of like, once you get to 21 (in the US at least), there are no more milestones to look forward to."* Ah but when you hit 100k you get a t-shirt and an outsized coffee mug. Isn't that something to look forward to?

Comment: _Instead, I think that reputation is a nice representation of the hard work that we have put into creating content here._ Disregards the myriad of important curation tasks that do not award any reputation. If you go by that key principle, helpful flags should give rep, closing should give rep, editing always should, deleting should, and review should.

Comment: @TravisJ Oh gods, making the reputation *even more* competitive would be terrible. We already have problems with people "rep farming" *instead of* applying quality control on the site like close voting, so your suggestion would just encourage even more of that.

Comment: "Earning 10k in a year is not that difficult," Depends on the tag. Most of my posts have been on low-traffic tags. If they had the *equivalent* reputation on say a Javascript tag, sure I'd probably have triple the score or more, but I still wouldn't be at 10k. What's awkward for me is that on some Betas, I have earned the moderator privileges and actively taken part. But on a site that I've been on for years and years, I can only look on reading meta posts complaining about queus building up and poor reviews. I'm not sure what the solution is, but I don't quite think this is working right.

Comment: @VLAZ - Your statement strongly lacks evidence, and makes some pretty broad accusations. What we need is more content, not more attention to posts who will only ever get <100 views in 10 years.

Comment: @Magisch - Why would we encourage removing material that is never found as opposed to creating material which helps tens of thousands of people?

Comment: @TravisJ You even [participated in the discussion about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357021/reputable-people-keep-answering-duplicates-whats-the-solution/357027)

Comment: @VLAZ - To note, my participation in that discussion was about prevention on the question asker end. That in no way supports your claim that more competition would be terrible. Nor does it bolster the other points you made. Moreover, a 20% increase in prevention from the asker side of the equation would outweigh the entirety of user moderation on content.

Comment: @TravisJ yet you *are* aware of the discussion about people going for points, rather than close voting? I wouldn't have thought this is some sort of unknown phenomenon that I am supposed to prove it exists - it's so wildly known that the FGTIW ("fastest gun in the west") acronym has been thrown around enough make it an actual casual way to of refering to these people. As well as the term "rep farming". [Mods have spoken about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316564). And I find it interesting that it's *me* who has to justify my claims, not you who suggested the change first.

Comment: @TravisJ to me it seems that resetting rep and forcing people to farm as much rep possible in short amount of time to restore their status would go against the goal of SO to be a repository of knowledge. No sense in referring to old stuff, if I can just post a quick answer and get my 10+ rep and just move on to the next. Post as many answers possible is the winning move if it's a race - spending time to find or even link a dupe doesn't earn points. If aggressive competitiveness was forced, I'd seriously reconsider my contribution to the site. You are free to rep farm, if you want.

Comment: @VLAZ - I am aware of the situation, but I dispute the claim that competition is "terrible" and that there are detrimental problems with high volume content production. Those two claims are what you would need to substantiate.

Comment: @VLAZ - RE: "Mods have spoken about this", that discussion has a downvote from me from a long time ago, and upvote on Shog's answer. He disputes the claim made there, adding it only cause problems to do and noting all of the progress in *prevention* that have been taken.

Comment: @VLAZ - It isn't resetting rep though, as you would still maintain not only a record of your previous rep, a record of your total rep, and generate rep based on previous posts. This would incentivize content creation and user participation.

Comment: @TravisJ yet your claim that it's going to be all rainbows and sunshine by introducing more competition is completely correct and doesn't require any proof. I bid you good night, then. You don't seem to be interested in actually listening but shutting me down by yelling "PROOF!"

Comment: @VLAZ - When the site opened there was some rather intense competition and it created a large amount of high quality content that is still around and has helped millions at this point. While there were different rules then and some material has been removed, that doesn't disprove the existing canon that was produced. Moreover, there is an undeniable downward trend in answering from the top content producers here, and this would be an attempt to get them more involved by increasing the fun of competition for them.

Comment: @TravisJ Right, you don't have any more proof than what I've offered then. But I am wrong because...reasons. Gotcha.

Comment: @VLAZ - You didn't offer any proof, so your argument doesn't really have any sort of backing. I gave you an example of where this has been similar before, as well as the fact that [a large number of high-reputation users have been decreasing their activity on the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252756/1026459) and the fact that 84% of >20k users have been slowing their answering activity. Can you hear me now?

Answer (score 17):

Admittedly this part of the "question" got me a bit worried:

> “I feel like I joined Stack Overflow too late. I feel stuck at the
>   bottom because I have almost no reputation and can’t do much.”

The reason, why this created a slight concern for me is, that I hope, that **SO will not ease the way for lower-reputation (in particular new) users to participate, in determining the quality of the content on the site.**

- I don't believe a new user has the capability to properly be able to judge, whether a question was of low or even high quality and whether it should be upvoted or downvoted.
- Sadly most new users are unable to determine, what is a quality question and what is simply a "do my coding project for me" request or an unanswarable question on SO *(this is being reflected in the quality of many questions that new users post)*.

I do sincerely hope, that the stance of the site will not change, in order to make newer users feel like they can participate, just because they feel unwelcomed / it's grindy. Yes it certainly takes some time to build the reputation, but this ensures the user user spends enough time on the website before he/she can be able to influence the outcome of the content.

I'd say it's even more important than we make it out to be, because whether we like to admit it or not, there is a bit of herd mentality, where a post, that is sitting at `-2` points (albeit unfairly) will get usually downvoted even further, meanwhile a bad post that's sitting at `1` point will usually stay that way *(obviously this may vary depending on which tags you frequent)*

---

What I however do think we should improve on:

- Make it clearer what the badges and privileges are
- Display them more clearly on the profile (currently it's a bit hidden as the interface only shows the latest / ongoing goal)
- Explain the importance of upvoting and downvoting and the power over regulating content
- *This is a subjective opinion:* Give users the ability to comment on their own question and answers straight away!

So the bottom line would be, don't give them power straight away, but rather a clear path towards achieving it and self-improvement.

Comment: _"Give users the ability to comment on their own question and answers straight away!"_ Isn't that already true, though? The 50-point privileges is for commenting anywhere, one can comment on their own questions and answers without it. Even this can go wrong, with new users occasionally lashing out at commenters. :(

Comment: Given the number of answers that should have been comments that I've seen over the years that were posted by newbies who don't have enough rep to post comments, I say, lower the bar for posting comments so we don't have to see so much of that going on (and so the mods don't have so much of it to clean up/convert to comments).

Comment: Thanks for sharing @rawrplus. I do think you can have high quality content while also inviting more people to participate. One doesn’t negate the other. Previous thinking assumed the two were mutually exclusive; nowadays we believe they can coexist. It’s a harder problem to solve, but a necessary one.

Comment: I never said they did. My main concern is the abuse of voting rights by newer users who are yet to understand the system properly.

Comment: I can understand this, though. I still remember clearly the "I can't do anything" struggle of not having enough reputation to ask a question but also not feeling/being smart enough to answer questions to gain the rep needed to ask a question. I now have a single answer that gains me 10-100 rep a month without doing anything, and in some ways I feel like I don't deserve those points; I'm not actively contributing. That kind of "easy rep gains" can seem like lost opportunities to the latecomers who have less chances for "passive income" style growth.

Comment: Making it easier for new users to earn points is not the only solution to the perceived problem, you could also make it harder for high-rep users to stay ahead. You could make old points expire, or have decreasing rewards, or the like.

Comment: @Flimm nobody would enjoy that change. That's essentially taking years away of somebody's hard work, especially if you are frequentign a not so popular tag where upvotes don't come so easily

Comment: @Rawrplus I would enjoy a change like that and I'm a high rep user on SO. But I take your point that some people wouldn't like it.

Answer (score 7):

Currently we have a progress bar on the profile page that shows us how far we are from our next privilege(s):

[image: Progress bar]

In the early stages of ones SO career this is a very helpful counter, but unfortunately it is hidden on your profile page. Which isn't that intuitive of a place to get to as you have to click on your reputation and badge counter to go there. If you set your own profile picture it helps, but especially with a system-generated picture it isn't all that obvious.

Couldn't we put the green progress bar, not the text around it, in the topbar or in the leftnav, as there is plenty of unused space there. On mouseover it could then display some useful hints. For example for a user with next to no reputation there could be a tooltip to say that one can:

> "Earn reputation by posting [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) or improve questions from other users by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) them."

In this way it is clear what is to be earned, and what it takes to earn that. Additionally we could also display some sort of leaderboard in the left-nav, as there is plenty empty space there, where one can easily see its current all-time, weekly, monthly rank. Where you can switch between the three through a cogwheel.

Comment: If you hover over the green bar bar your mouse doesn't turn into a hand, making me forget it's clickable to show a pop-up to then be able to find what 'Approve tag wiki edits' is. It's even more annoying IMO with tag badges.

Answer (score 5):

> Most participants **didn’t know they could earn reputation by editing other people’s questions and answers**.

This is the most surprising one to me because it seems like a lot people incorrectly assume that flagging, down voting, closing, and deleting posts increases your reputation. I thought that was born out of an assumption that *all* actions increase your reputation (or at least the ones that affect posts). Or maybe it is and the folks who responded just didn't make those assumptions.

> How I see someone’s question isn’t the way that they see their question.”

This sounds like they imagined their edits changing the intent of the post. I'd like to know how the rest of that part of the interview went. Was the purpose of editing explained at that point? Were they still adverse when told it's mainly for fixing grammar, formatting, spelling, clarity, etc. or did you not go that deep into explaining each privilege?

Answer (score 4):

**Note**: This answer is not about reputation, but about these UX posts in general.

1. **Visibility**.
   I use SO when getting answers from Google searches. I normally don't look at the current meta posts, as they don't effect me. I also think a fair amount of other users do this too, and so won't see these posts.

   Can there be a way for these posts to appear in all Stack Exchange sites, like featured Meta.SE posts do?
   If, for whatever reason, this isn't possible is there an email subscription I can get for these posts?
2. **Updates**.
   I've read through the previous post, and saw you're "now wrapping up the first phase of information gathering for this project." But, other than a link, I don't see any updates on this - no edit or comment here.

   <sub>(Rhetorical)</sub>
   Has it left the first information gathering phase? If it has what's the plan now? What's going to come of this?

   Can we have a status update on previous posts?

I like seeing these posts as the optimist in me hopes it'll help break the general distaste between Stack Exchange Inc and its users.

It's also nice to be able to see where the site, I've put a large portion of time, is moving. And to give feedback if I feel strongly about a certain aspect of the proposed changes, ***before it's released***.

Comment: Hi @peilonrayz! Re: visibility - you can set up email alerts by going to stackexchange.com > Filtered Questions. You can filter by the tag ux-research-time.

Comment: Re: updates - the goal of these updates is to provide folks here with more visibility into one of the inputs we use to make product decisions. Sharing further updates about project progress is not currently in scope.

Comment: @Donna I can't find a way to get email alerts, however I have found an  atom feed on [that page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ux-research-time?sort=Newest&edited=true).

Comment: @Donna I have research turned on in my email setting yet never received anything about any of these (I'll assume because I am over 1k on a few sites). I know you suggest using a filter email - I'll stick to my feed on WB - but was this lack of email for those who have turned on research email alerts intentional or just the emails did not go out?

Comment: Hi @jgreenwell! We appreciate your interest in participating in research :) We usually conduct research in small batches, so only a small group of folks will get an email requesting their participation per research project. However, we conduct research on an ongoing basis and, depending on the project, target people of different backgrounds (so this particular project targeted low-rep users, others target high rep and/or other criteria). So while you may not have gotten an email yet, I expect you’ll get one at some point as long as you stay opted-in to the Research email list :)

Comment: @Donna ah, thought so with this one. I asked because the email settings were mentioned in post but I haven't seen any notice of this project at all (presumably because it is only meant for low-rep users).

Answer (score 4):

> What have been your experiences with reputation and privileges?

I don't see any major issues with the points system. I have, however, seen a lot of bad edits allowed/good edits rejected. My assumption is this happens because of 'personal preference' and not paying attention to the OP's question, or what the answer is really saying. I noticed this once I got to the queue.

> What motivates you to participate in Stack Overflow?

The most important thing, and what gets me coming back, is to be able to find great questions and great answers when I myself am searching for something. I want to have clear concise Q&A out there so it helps the next developer with the same question. I try to go out of my way to fix what I can because I believe its for the greater good, and would cause less confusion.

> How, if at all, have these things changed if you’ve gained reputation over time?

I started paying more attention to what I put out there as my reputation rose. It takes more effort but because of the privilege/points system, you get a reward of sorts for doing so.

> What could be improved on?

- Like @Rawrpruls mentioned above: Explain the importance of upvoting, downvoting and the power over regulating content in clearer detail.
- Although there is a good system for weeding out bad edits/queue edits, maybe raise some of the queue levels while keeping the privileges below them the same?
- Greatly emphasize that an upvote won't kill you. People hold on to them like it's their last dollar.

> Final Thoughts:

I have had to deal with edit wars because stuff got approved that shouldn't have and a moderator had to get involved to roll back the change. It's the culture of SO sometimes. I am not certain how to filter out the good from the bad in those cases. I am sure this is taken care of more clearly in the background than it is noticed by the community. Overall SO and Stack Exchange have a great system going. I am looking forward to seeing what changes come of this.

Answer (score 4):

As a relatively low rep user on most SE sites, felt like I should chip in:

> What have been your experiences with reputation and privileges?

**Impedes access**

I find rep impedes the usability of the site. There was a case where I wanted to contribute an in-depth answer (including functional code example) for Excel spreadsheet searches, and I was blocked by the 'low quality' answers, where I had to explicitly make a meta post to ask what to do (it required a mod to temporarily remove the low quality block).

**Difficult to earn rep to gain access**

Earning enough rep to overcome the first hurdle is difficult, especially if you don't have anything useful to contribute elsewhere (either due to the fact easier questions already have good answers, or adding comments tends to get glossed over). It can take a number of days to even get over the 10 point requirement, and who is going to hold a post in lieu for several days?

**Possible implicit stigma on questions**

I also think there's an implicit stigma against low rep users when it comes to asking questions. I find the proportion of effort put into answering my question (if it's even answered) is proportionate to my rep amount, rather than any intrinsic quality of the question (specifity, title accuracy, willingness to reply to commented queries to clarify etc don't improve uptake).

When observing the questions with a lot of good answers, 9 times out of 10 it's someone with a high reputation score asking the question (if it wasn't featured on HNQ). Similarly, you'll see answer voting almost similarly; lower rep users more likely to be nearer the bottom, higher rep users nearer to the top.

**What it feels like**

It almost feels like being penalised for being low rep, even if that's not intended. A question I feel like I could ask on SE, I tend to shake my head at (even if there could be a knowledgeable expert on the subject), as it's typical not to get an answer, or for an answer to take many days to appear, and thus the frustration of scraping the search barrel for a tidbit of insight that might waste hours of my time seems preferable to the 'maybe, maybe not' anxious wait of an answer on SE.

Part of me feels like hiding reputation amounts (only seen on username hover) might be the way to go to help mitigate it.

Comment: *I was blocked by the 'low quality' answers...* I don't think that's a reputation thing, at least not by itself.

Answer (score 4):

I love Stack Overflow because I generally find answers to my questions here.  Most times I don't need to ask a questions here because someone else already has asked that question.  But when I do ask a question, I almost feel like I'm getting shamed for asking it.  Thus, I ask as few questions as possible.

Sometimes I'd like to up-vote a response that helped me out.  Nope, sorry... I can't do that because my reputation is 6.   I feel basically locked out of contributing and giving back to a community that has given me so much.

Answer (score 1):

I think one problem for new users is that they can't do anything other than asking a question or answering one which in turn gets a lot of attention. If you work in a niche field your question won't get much attention, and if you have a question for a popular technology it has probably already been asked.

The same goes for answering, unless you monitor the new question queue for your best known topic, chances are slim to be able to answer it before any of the long term members does.

I understand the reason to not let anyone comment, as it will be abused for spamming, but on the other hand I think the hurdle for new users to really get involved is too high. You feel like an outsider to an elitist group of high rep contributors.

What I also experienced is anonymous (no reason in the comment) downvoting for any question I posted, but to be honest this was more the case in SciFi than in SO. But this also is very discouraging if you just lose the hard gained rep to seemingly someone who doesn't want to have new contributors on the site.

One really good thing is the cross-site-rep which you get when you join on of the other sites after you already gained some rep on the one you started. You don't have to hassle to gain the first 100 points again.

Comment: "*What I also experienced is anonymous (no reason in the comment) downvoting for any question I posted*" this is really annoying. Some times I feel there is a bot serially downvoting each new question and each answer to the question.

Comment: Considering that votes are anonymous by design, and that there are no intentions to ever change this, can you make a feasible suggestion to improve the experience of users receiving anonymous downvotes?

Comment: By the way: most perceptions of certain downvotes being unfair, unreasonable, made by "bots" or by people who don't know the subject, or don't like new contributors, are very biased. It is hard to take people seriously here on Meta when assuming poor intentions from the downvoters you don't even know who really are. For all that it's worth, a similar reasoning could even be applied to excessive upvoting.

Comment: @E_net4 I wrote "seemingly", because I still have no idea why there were/are so many downvotes on some questions/answers. All I am saying is that for new users this feels like they are not welcome here for whatever reason. And no, I don't have the solution for this problem. But maybe if you have to provide some reason from a few options it would make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Again, that is often a biased point of view. My own bias stands on the opposite end. I notice several questions receiving a large amount of upvotes without the post matching them in quality. In turn, these questions may become exceedingly tricky review audits, tripping our reviewers and comprising their curation labor ([one remarkable example here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373705/1233251)).

Comment: Great points, I think your comment about it being problematic that new users are not able to do things except asking and answering questions (which get a lot of attention) is spot on. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: @E_net4, But your employing such perceptions yourself. If I get downvotes on a post about WPF, and the commentors state: "While your answer works, it's complex and unmaintainable", "Your approach is obsolete as of two version prior, check this link here", "This is a solution, but it could be confusing to someone not strong in MVVC and errors could lead to memory leaks", I'm pretty sure they know what they are talking about and that I can address these concerns. If I just get some downvotes...??? My grammar is poor? Never heard of WPF and it scares you? Woke up grumpy this morning?

Comment: @E_net4, And I'm saying that from the perspective of an experienced user of this site. Imagine what it's like for a new user who posts a question/answer in good faith, that's really not so bad overall. A bit of useful criticism, and they could maybe fix it up. Commentless downvotes? ? ?? Unless they are practiced in the arts of telepathy, can you blame them for filling in whatever blanks have been left wide open for them to fill? Not all of these posters will assume the same thing, but some will assume some of the things that you assumed in broad sweeping strokes.

Comment: @ouflak Not knowing the reason behind a downvote is a common concern, but not one which weighs enough to counter the [many reasons against forced feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1233251). And from the moment someone says the downvote was made for no good reason, no assumptions are being made from whoever calls them out. The main purpose of downvoting is incompatible with the human condition of feeling attacked by them. We do encourage not to take them personally.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: Obviously some  people have read this and took it the wrong way. By no means do I encourage people to ask code (or otherwise) intensive questions that are "homeworky". But someone who is shunned off the site for asking too much in one post could have answered one of your, or many others' questions much better than anyone else and you would have never known. That being said...

One thing that I've seen happen quite a few times (which is a very bad thing about reputation and experienced users' perception of newcomers), is a newcomer with little to no reputation asking a question. Now, as a new user (I personally think) it shouldn't be expected to know they can't ask a "duplicate" question or make people "do your homework". So when a newcomer does make a post like this, a lot of people shun them with comments and down-votes, literally discouraging from using the site at all (especially since now they've got negative rep and only negative user interactions from the site). This even happened to me when I first joined with a duplicate question, and the negative rep and frustration made me not want to contribute at all for a long time.

I'm not saying it's not right to let newcomers know there's a question just like theirs, or we won't do all the work for them. They should be told that's not what this site is for, referred to the site rules, and have their question removed.

I think a good solution to this problem (especially if a newcomer's bad first question never gets deleted, or they don't know how to themselves) would be to make users with less than 5 reputation not be able to lose reputation until they've received at least 5 reputation. By that time they should really know how the site works, and at least they still have an incentive to continue using the site the right way and not lose any of their 5 rep.

Just a thought, but am open to any opinions/fact checks/criticism

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that your first experience was frustrating. Thanks for sharing and welcome to the community :)

Comment: @Donna It's positive that the OP believes it would help if the curation in these cases takes place. The objection appears to be *how* that's happening. One problem from the curators' side of this is that it takes a lot of time and effort to write a diplomatic comment pointing these things out. Perhaps an additional "flag" set with pre-written, helpful guiding comments - available to those with *n*-rep - could smooth some waves, here...

Comment: You're also saying someone who could potentially answer someone else's question on a different subject but just so happened to not know what he asked is intensive isn't welcome on the site?

Comment: And @CindyMeister of course there should be a pre-written notice for both cases that could just show up as a notification and deletes their post. Easy enough.

Comment: Fact check: there is no negative rep. If a user has 1 rep point and receives a downvote, they don't lose reputation points. Also, "spiteful" is too negative a word to be employed towards people who disagree with you.

Comment: You describe experienced users of the site who disagree with you as spiteful. Nice.

Comment: Negative rep is not currently a thing. It's hard capped at +1, so if you recieve downvotes at 1 Reputation, it stays at 1. I don't see how increasing that number to 5 would make a difference, as you barely unlock anything from the difference of 4. And I question that 5 reputation is where you should know how it works, that's literally one upvote or two edited posts.

Comment: To  make matters worse I have gotten downvoted for answering a question that was marked as a duplicate

Comment: @CoderJoe We have other questions on Meta covering that subject (e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334361/1233251)).

Comment: That doesnt really cover the topic of a person posting an answer to the question it pertains to the question itself @E_net4

Comment: @CoderJoe You are free to look for a more suitable question or ask your own. The problem should be the same however.

Comment: I'm wondering if a more thorough understanding of what SO is trying to accomplish would help with the frustration aspect.  Their question gets closed, but knowing the goal could probably help alleviate why it happened.

Comment: Even if rep can't go *negative*, it can be a big hole to dig out of if you're trying to build up a little rep, and the couple good questions/answers that have elevated you from 0 to 10 to 15 are erased from a single bad one.  I imagine losing fairly earned rep is a lot more discouraging than a brand new user account staying at `+1`

Comment: I get this, the worst experience I had was being mocked by one of the top ten users of this site for asking in essence why `print('a');print('b')` is slower than `print('a\nb')`. Even now I don't know why that question deserved to be mocked, or the answer... :/

Answer (score -3):

I find it unfortunate that the desire for more relevant questions that was voiced in the answers was ignored and not considered part of "core Q&A". Stack Overflow is lacking good ways for users to search for questions they consider to be relevant.

Currently, I have three only three ways to classify a tag. It's either "watched tag", "normal tag" or "ignored tag". It would be possible to have more classification levels to allow users filter better for questions they consider to be interesting.

Among experienced users it seems to me like there are people who want to help newcomers and others that don't enjoy answering questions by newcomers. If Stack Overflow would give a new privilege for users that have reached 5000 reputation to filter out all posts by users with less then 50 reputation from the front page, they would find more questions that they like to engage with. They would also engage in less downvoting of newcomers without providing comments.

That said, I do consider reputation to be valuable. I like to be able to raise the visibility of one of my questions by adding a bounty to the question.
I like the privilege to be able to edit without the need for approval and to be able to see deleted questions and answers.

Comment: _"users that have reached 5000 reputation to filter out all posts by users with less then 50 reputation"_ User reputation makes a very poor metric for question quality, though. This would make a poor and sometimes upsetting discrimination of questions. [This proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253351/1233251) presents better filtering criteria.

Answer (score -3):

I understand that SO needs more users to increase their ad revenue which is how this resource for us all gets financed. So that means being welcoming to new users.

But two concerns for me about increasing powers for low rep users.

First, the concern about [free riders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-rider_problem).

> the free-rider problem occurs when those who benefit from resources, public goods, or services do not pay for them, which results in an underprovision of those goods or services. For example, a free-rider may frequently ask for available parking lots (public goods) from those who have already paid for them, in order to benefit from free parking. That is, the free-rider may use the parking even more than the others without paying a penny. The free-rider problem is the question of how to limit free riding and its negative effects in these situations. The free-rider problem may occur when property rights are not clearly defined and imposed. The free-rider problem is common with goods which are non-excludable, including public goods and situations of the Tragedy of the Commons.

Reputation measures, crudely, the value of an SO participant and the claim they can rightly make on the system that they benefit from.  Too many free riders making too many demands and SO collapses as high reputation users decide that they don't get enough value for the effort they put into the site.

The second concern is the [Dunning-Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect)

> the Dunning–Kruger effect is a cognitive bias in which people mistakenly assess their cognitive ability as greater than it is. It is related to the cognitive bias of illusory superiority and comes from the inability of people to recognize their lack of ability. Without the self-awareness of metacognition, people cannot objectively evaluate their competence or incompetence.

New SO users are incompetent at knowing how bad they are at asking good questions and providing good answers.  Reputation and the privileges therein provide both a way of checking problems from DKE (such as entitlment and outrage) and as a way of showing other users how susceptible a user may be to DKE.

Good reputation comes from providing value.  Other than encouraging users to provide value, I don't see that any changes need to be made in the reputation system.

Comment: *But two concerns for me about increasing powers for low rep users.* The post isn't about increasing powers for users with low reputation. It said they aren't even interested/aware of privileges beyond commenting.

Comment: @BSMP if that's the case then why study this issue at all?

Comment: @KevinJohnsrude How would they have known this without studying it?